# Elegantly implementing 'map (+1) list' in ruby

Tags: ruby

The short code in title is in Haskell, it does things like

```
list.map {|x| x + 1}
```

in ruby.

While I know that manner, but what I want to know is, is there any more elegant manners to implement same thing in ruby like in Haskell.

I really love the `to_proc` shortcut in ruby, like this form:

```
[1,2,3,4].map(&:to_s)
[1,2,3,4].inject(&:+)
```

But this only accept exactly matching argument number between the Proc's and method.

I'm trying to seek a way that allow passing one or more arguments extra into the Proc, and without using an useless temporary block/variable like what the first demonstration does.

I want to do like this:

```
[1,2,3,4].map(&:+(1))
```

Does ruby have similar manners to do this?

Comment: I saw a gem the other day, but I can’t remember what it was called other than `X`.

Comment: @JoshLee If you can recall the gem, that would be very appreciated.

Comment: Aha, saw it on Hacker News. http://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=4003805

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [ampex](http://cirw.in/blog/ampex) gem, which lets you use methods of `X` to build up any proc one one variable. Here’s an example from its spec:

```
["a", "b", "c"].map(&X * 2).should == ["aa", "bb", "cc"]
```

Answer (score 7):

If you just want to add one then you can use the [`succ` method](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Integer.html#method-i-succ):

```
>> [1,2,3,4].map(&:succ)
=> [2, 3, 4, 5]
```

If you wanted to add two, you could use a lambda:

```
>> add_2 = ->(i) { i + 2 }
>> [1,2,3,4].map(&add_2)
=> [3, 4, 5, 6]
```

For arbitrary values, you could use a lambda that builds lambdas:

```
>> add_n = ->(n) { ->(i) { i + n } }
>> [1,2,3,4].map(&add_n[3])
=> [4, 5, 6, 7]
```

You could also use a lambda generating method:

```
>> def add_n(n) ->(i) { i + n } end
>> [1,2,3,4].map(&add_n(3))
=> [4, 5, 6, 7]
```

Comment: Not add one only. It seems I have to change the example codes to prevent misunderstanding ;-)

Comment: @ShouYa: But that's why there's all the `add_n` stuff as well.

Answer (score 3):

You can't do it directly with the default `map`. However it's quite easy to implement a version that supports this type of functionality. As an example [Ruby Facets](http://rubyworks.github.com/facets/) includes just such a method:

```
require 'facets/enumerable'

[1, 2, 3, 4].map_send(:+, 10)
=> [11, 12, 13, 14]
```

The implementation looks like this:

```
def map_send(meth, *args, &block)
  map { |e| e.send(meth, *args, &block) }
end
```

Answer (score 2):

In *this particular* case, you can use the following:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4].map(&1.method(:+))
```

However, this only works because `+` is not associative. It wouldn't work for `-`, for example.

Answer (score 1):

Ruby hasn't built-in support for this feature, but you can create your own extension or use small gem '[ampex](http://cirw.in/blog/ampex)'. It defines global variable X with extended 'to_proc' functionality.

It gives you possibility to do that:

```
[1,2,3].map(&X.+(1))
```

Or even that:

```
"alpha\nbeta\ngamma\n".lines.map(&X.strip.upcase)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to add 1, you can use `next` or `succ`:

```
[1,2,3,4].map(&:next)
[1,2,3,4].map(&:succ)
```